# elevateZoom on BSCarousel bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a bootstrap carousel with a elevateZoom lens inside it. The issue is that when the mouse leaves the image, the lens does not disappear until the mouse leaves the lens too. In the [example shown in official elevateZoom web](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#lens-zoom) this does not happen(the lens disappear as soon as the mouse leaves the image).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="planos" class="carousel slide" style="border-top:1px solid #FCF3E8; top:-1px" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" ng-app="planos-module" ng-controller="planos-controller">
        <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index" class="item" id="plano{{$index+1}}">
            <img ng-src="img/planos/{{$index+1}}.jpg" alt="Plano {{$index+1}}" data-zoom-image="img/planos/{{$index+1}}.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control carousel-control-2" href="#planos" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control carousel-control-2" href="#planos" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the relevant javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some code
    $('#plano1').addClass('active');
    $('#planos .item img').each(function(){
        $(this).elevateZoom({
            zoomType   : "lens",
            lensShape : "round",
            lensSize    : 350
        });
    });
    //some more code
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

EDIT: [Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkgmdfv8/1/). I wasn't able to replicate it exactly as my web, but the same issue is going on. Also, I couldn't import the elevateZoom js file, so I just copy-pasted its content in the js fiddle (if you scroll down in the JS section you can see my code)

EDIT2: SOLVED! The answer is below.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle

Comment: @Vishnu Edited. Check it out, I would really appreciate if you could give me a hand here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Here is the answer, in case anyone else experiences the same issue.

I just had to add `containLensZoom: true` option to my elevateZoom initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some code
    $('#plano1').addClass('active');
    $('#planos .item img').each(function(){
        $(this).elevateZoom({
            zoomType   : "lens",
            lensShape : "round",
            lensSize    : 350,
            containLensZoom : true
        });
    });
    //some more code
});
```